# 1980's book that had a small paper rocket ship the reader would push across the page and through little slotted holes to get to the next page

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a book I had as a little boy in the early 1980's about a rocket ship.

It had a small paper rocket ship that I would push across the page and through little slotted holes to get through to the next page.

It was very cool and I'd love to buy a used copy but I'm having trouble searching as I don't know the name or any details.

Comment: Also, if there are any prominent Science Fiction tropes (warp drives, aliens, planets with a single rose and a prince, etc), those are always good to [edit] in because it can help guide people to an answer.

Comment: This looks like it might be similar.  https://kidsbooks.com/products/9781523501137B/rocket-a-journey-through-the-pages-book

Answer (score 2):

Similar to this?
It says the little rocket ship is plastic.
[image]

https://kidsbooks.com/products/9781523501137B/rocket-a-journey-through-the-pages-book